# Bubble sort defect using inline assembly code

Tags: sorting, pointers, stack, inline-assembly, bubble-sort

I am making a bubble sort function in assembly code for my computer systems class.

My function looks like this

```
 int sorter(int* list, int count, int opcode) {
 __asm {
        mov ebx, opcode             ; opcode in ebx
        push 0                      ; outer count
        mov ecx, 0                  ; start ecx at 0 to start loop
        mov esi, list               ; set esi to list value/ starting address
        jmp iloop                   ; jump to inner loop
    oloop:                          //OUTER LOOP
        push ecx                    ;
        mov ecx, 0                  ; put the 2nd value in the list in the inner loop count
    iloop:                          // inner loop
        mov edx, dword ptr[esi + 4 * ecx]; move first value in edx
        mov eax, dword ptr[esi + 4 + 4 * ecx]; move next value in list to eax
        cmp ebx, 2                  ; compare opcode with 2 
        je dsnd                     ; if opcode is equal to 2 then we are using descending order
        cmp eax, edx                ; compare values at eax and edx
        jg no_swap                  ; if value is greater eax(2nd value) then dont swap /ascending order
    cont:                           //continue from descend
        push edx                    ; push contents of edx to stack
        pop dword ptr[esi + 4 + 4 * ecx]; pop the contents on stack to address of value in eax
        push eax                    ; push value in eax to stack
        pop dword ptr[esi + 4 * ecx]; pop value on stack to address of value previously in eax
    no_swap:                        //no  value swap
        inc ecx                     ; increment inner count
        cmp ecx, count              ; compare inner loop count to acutal length
        jne iloop                   ; if not equal jump back to inner loop
        pop ecx                     ; get outer count
        inc ecx                     ; to check for n-1 in outer loop
        cmp ecx, count              ; compare outer loop count to length
        jne oloop                   ; if not equal jump back to outer loop
        jmp done                    ;
    dsnd:
        cmp eax, edx                ; compare values at eax and edx
        jl no_swap                  ; if value is less then dont swap
        jmp cont                    ; continue with loop

    done:
    }
```

Where `opcode` is either `1` for ascending sort or `2` for descending order,
`list` is a pointer to list of ints, and `count` is the number of ints in the list

For ascending sort, my program works fine, but with descending I have issues as shown in these test runs:

```
input 10 -20 5 12 30 -5 -22 55 52 0
Number of integer = 10
Ascend_or_Descend = 1
-22 -20 -5 0 5 10 12 30 52 55    # correct

input 48 -24 48 -24 10 100 -10 60 -256 10 -10 4096 -1024 60 10 -10
Number of integer = 16
Ascend_or_Descend = 1
-1024 -256 -24 -24 -10 -10 -10 10 10 10 48 48 60 60 100 4096 # correct

input 10 -20 5 12 30 -5 -22 55 52 0
Number of integer = 10
Ascend_or_Descend = 2
4283780 55 52 30 12 10 5 0 -5 -20 # incorrect

input 48 -24 48 -24 10 100 -10 60 -256 10 -10 4096 -1024 60 10 -10
Number of integer = 16
Ascend_or_Descend = 2
1500056 4096 100 60 60 48 48 10 10 10 -10 -10 -10 -24 -24 -256 # incorrect
```

It seems to take the lowest value and swaps it with an address. I am no expert with assembly.

Comment: Most of the edits were code blocking for clarity. I fixed up some prose where is was difficult to read.

Comment: Your "swapping in" guess is good, but I don't think it an address but rather the junk value at `list[-1]`. I suggest making higher level pseudo-code of the task like `if decending then: goto dsnd` or `swap this element with the next` and see if your code conforms to your higher level intentions.